# How Download generated APKs using the Play Developer Publishing API

Tags: android, api, download, google-play-developer-api

Is there a way to download APK file from google play?

I need to transfer the apk to a device without internet connection.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/download-apks

Comment: you can use transfer vie usb and , and click the apk it will load to phone, but u have to accept "allows all unknown sources " in security menu

Comment: I need to send an apk via bluetooth to another device without internet, how can I download an apk of mine from the playstore?

Comment: I am not get it, what u want to do, but as I said from outsource u can send with mail, chat,.....etc